# Simple sql query problem

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hi I have this query in ms access which is somehow not working. All I need to do is to pull out donator name from donator table with the id of volunteer. But I need to get user input, volunteer name and pull out the related volunteer first. Please help.

`SELECT volunteer.id, volunteer.name, donator.* FROM volunteer, donator WHERE Volunteer.id = Donator.vid AND Volunteer.name = Forms!frm5!Combo2;`

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, what does it say? Or are you just getting zero rows? And if so, does it work when you hard code the value (the one you are currently getting from the form)?

Comment: getting zero rows. form value are just the data from volunteer table.

Comment: Does it work when you do something like "SELECT volunteer.id, volunteer.name, donator.* FROM volunteer, donator WHERE Volunteer.id = Donator.vid AND Volunteer.name = 'John Smith'"

Comment: so does it work when you do it in its simplest form -- "select * from volunteer where name = 'somename'  " ?

Comment: It sounds like perhaps you are displaying the name, but querying on the id. Is that possible?

Comment: I am of course guessing, but you said the value (Forms!frm5!Combo2) was just from the table. But which value from the table? Is it the Id or the Text? It is common to use a lookup table like that, but hide the ID field, thus displaying only the name field.

Comment: oh its a name field from volunteer table. It display correct in drop down list.

Comment: That's my point. "It displays correctly" does not mean it is using the correct value. I think we need more information to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Check your case on Database names.  For instance, you reference volunteer.name and Volunteer.id.  In some DB's, fields are case sensitive.

Also, you'd want to quote your volunteer name field.